# Unable to load CSS and JS files with forbidden error

Tags: html, css

I have uploaded index.html file into my server, but the css file does not load. I also updated .htaccess file, but still the css does not load. I tried adding "?", changed permissions, but still no avail.

My CSS Code:

```
<!-- CSS here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slicknav.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/progressbar_barfiller.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/gijgo.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.min.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animated-headline.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome-all.min.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nice-select.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

My .htaccess file

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted

Html file path:

[www.veloxconsulting.in/im/index.html](http://www.veloxconsulting.in/im/index.html)

When I try to access the file via url, I get below error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your path to the CSS files. Try adding ./ before the path
Also I am not sure why you added a question mark in the end. Try removing that as well

This line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?">
```

will be like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Still the CSS does not load. When I try to access the CSS through url, I get below error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Path to the css file: veloxconsulting.in/im/assets/css/style.css

Comment: What is the Apache server version? Is it 2.4 or higher?

Comment: No, I'm not using any apache server. It's only a website template, which is downloaded and uploaded after editing.

Comment: Your hosting provider will be using the Apache Server. You can see the version on the hosting dashboard (where this is hosted - http://www.veloxconsulting.in/)

Also one workaround would be to delete the .htaccess file on the server (please keep a backup before you delete it from the server)